# Has anyone built an nhibernate provider for Microsoft Index Server?

Tags: nhibernate, indexing

This may be an odd question! But I was wondering if anyone has ever attempted this. I guess the first question most people would ask is why!!

With index server you can add additional meta data to standard file information (name, size etc).

I want to be able to expose this information through to a BL component via nhibernate I need to write - so that when I replace the indexing, I don't have to rewrite the Business logic.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you would extract interface for indexing provider and then create a wrapper and wrap Micorosoft Index Server. Then when you have different provider, you create a wrapper for the new one and use IoC to inject implementation. I fail to see how NHibernate fits into this.

Comment: The legacy solution I have is that index server has be used as a meta database and I'd rather sit nhibernate on top of it to build some BL - and then later replace it because of time constraints.